# Base64 String to PNG Image For itextsharp

Tags: .net, base64, itext

I have a 3rd party control that allows for signature capture.  I am capturing the image of the signature from the control in the form of a base64 string.  But I need to be able to then stamp this image to a PDF document using itextsharp, but can't get this base64 string to convert to an acceptable format (PNG).

Example of the data being captured by the control that I need to get onto an existing PDF document using itextsharp:

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

Comment: When I decode your data I don't recognize it as any known image format, definitely not PNG. So what format is the control exporting in?

Comment: I've checked all the documentation I can find with the control.  All I know is that it is a base64 encoded string.  I've emailed the developer for more information.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Developer of control has provided a method for doing this.  All better.

Comment: How this answer will help to anyone?